# Oracle - sql_text truncated to 20 characters for CREATE/ALTER/GRANT statements?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I seem to be running into an odd issue with Oracle not storing/returning the full SQL text for queries.  I was monitoring currently active queries by joining `v$session` to `v$sqltext` when I noticed that all of the `CREATE TABLE ____ AS` queries had a `sql_text` value that was truncated to 20 characters.

For example:

```
SQL> SELECT sql_text, LENGTH(sql_text), sql_fulltext, LENGTH(sql_fulltext) FROM v$sql WHERE sql_id = 'sql_id_here';

SQL_TEXT                            LENGTH(SQL_TEXT) SQL_FULLTEXT                        LENGTH(SQL_FULLTEXT)
----------------------------------- ---------------- ----------------------------------- --------------------
create table schema.                              20 create table schema.                                  20

1 row selected.


SQL> SELECT sql_text, LENGTH(sql_text) FROM v$sqltext WHERE sql_id = 'sql_id_here';

SQL_TEXT                            LENGTH(SQL_TEXT)
----------------------------------- ----------------
create table schema.                              20

1 row selected.

SQL> SELECT sql_text, LENGTH(sql_text) FROM v$sqltext_with_newlines WHERE sql_id = 'sql_id_here';

SQL_TEXT                            LENGTH(SQL_TEXT)
----------------------------------- ----------------
create table schema.                              20

1 row selected.
```

I thought it might be an isolated incident, so I checked *all* `CREATE TABLE` entries in `v$sqltext`:

```
SELECT sql_id, COUNT(*) AS entries, SUM(LENGTH(sql_text)) AS query_len
FROM v$sqltext
WHERE sql_id IN (
    SELECT sql_id
    FROM v$sqltext
    WHERE piece = 0
      AND UPPER(sql_text) LIKE 'CREATE TABLE%'
)
GROUP BY sql_id
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Of over 250+ sql_id entries, all had `entries = 1` and `query_len = 20`.

However, if I check `dba_audit_trail` once the query finishes (assuming I know in advance what table is being created), the full sql_text is present there.

What's going on and how I can fix this so `v$sqltext` contains the full query for `CREATE TABLE ___ AS` statements?

---

**Edit:** Upon closer inspection, it appears that all `GRANT`, `CREATE`, and `ALTER` queries are truncated to 20 characters in `v$sqltext`.  All other queries contain their full text.  I'm opening a bounty to hopefully get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Have you tried to execute something like `select sql_text from v$sqltext where sql_id = '...'` to see, what exactly this view contains for one of sql_id's? Just to exclude all possible errors in previous queries. If this view really contains just part of query, I would like to think it is a bug.

Comment: @Dmitry - I did.  I checked `sql_text` and `sql_fulltext` from `v$sqltext` as well as `sql_text` from `v$sqltext_with_newlines`.  This only seems to be an issue with CTAS queries, everything else seems to show up fine.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I am pretty sure this is an isolated issue. I ran `select a.*,length(a.sql_text) From v$sqltext a
where upper(sql_text) like '%CREATE TABLE%';` and got lengths upto 64 characters. Same with `ALTER` and `GRANT`. I am on 11gR2.

Comment: I wonder if there is some security restrictions causing this.  I would hate to see statements like `alter user me identified by "myNewPassword";` show up in `V$SQL`.

Comment: Checked against 12.1.0.2, got lengths up to 64 chars, too.

Comment: I'm starting to think this may have been a settings or audit misconfiguration, but last I checked I never saw a setting for "truncate sql text to N characters but keep the full text in the audit trail".  Any settings suggestions would be fantastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a known issue with 11.2.0.4. If you have access to My Oracle Support, look at bug 19634213; and bugs 18431964, 20308798 and maybe 18245071 (which isn't public). I obviously can't go into any detail or reproduce what they say. From nop77svk's comment it may have been fixed in 12c, but could also be platform-specific.

If this is causing a problem you'll need to raise a service request with Oracle to verify you are hitting the same thing and to find out if a patch is available.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  Bug 19634213 is exactly what we're dealing with.  So far it doesn't look like there's a workaround aside from upgrading to Oracle 12 (which isn't an option for us).  Hopefully they'll roll out a fix for this in the near future.