# Oracle DDL statment ( like CTAS) , after executed, not show in V$SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

Why Oracle "DDL" statements (like "CTAS"), after executed, does not shown in V$SQL view ?
How can get "SQL_ID" of that? I want to use "SQL_ID" in SQl plan baselines. TNX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V$SQL shows just the first 20 charachter for CTAS. It is a bug in Oracle Database 11g. For more details, see: ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623646/oracle-sql-text-truncated-to-20-characters-for-create-alter-grant-statements/28087571#28087571\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623646/oracle-sql-text-truncated-to-20-characters-for-create-alter-grant-statements/28087571#28087571%5C))[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623646/oracle-sql-text-truncated-to-20-characters-for-create-alter-grant-statements/28087571#28087571).

Answer (score 0):

CTAS operations appear in the `v$sql` view

```
SQL> create table t1 as select * from dba_objects ;

Table created.

SQL> select sql_text,sql_id from v$sql where sql_text like '%create table t1 as select%' ;

SQL_TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID
-------------
create table t1 as select * from dba_objects
4j5kv6x7cz5r7

select sql_text,sql_id from v$sql where sql_text like '%create table t1 as selec
t%'
5n4xnjkt3vz3h
```

SQL Plan Baselines are part of SPM ( SQL Plan Management )

> A SQL plan baseline. A plan baseline is a set of accepted plans that
> the optimizer is  allowed to use for a SQL statement. In the typical
> use case, the database accepts a plan into the plan baseline only
> after verifying that the plan performs well. In this context, a plan
> includes all plan-related information (for example, SQL plan
> identifier, set of hints, bind values, and optimizer environment) that
> the optimizer needs to reproduce an execution plan.

If you are using a CTAS recurrently, I guess you are doing it in batch mode, thus dropping the table and then recreate it afterwards using the mentioned CTAS command. I would rather try to see what is the problem with the SELECT itself of that statement.

But SQL Baselines are more focus for solving queries which plans can be fixed and evolved as the optimizer is not always choosing the best one.

Comment: I created a test table and used below query, but does not shown in V$SQL view "select sql_text,sql_id from v$sql where sql_text like '%create table t1 as selec
t%'". I am using Oracle Database 11g.

Comment: of course it doesn't. Your query contains `selec t%'` and it should be `select%`